# Single cell with data bar and fixed min/max values

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel sheet tracking progress of a project, I have a column of percentage values representing progress on each individual task, plus a single cell at the bottom that summarizes the overall progress of the project:

[image: Excel sheet tracking progress of a project]

On the "summary cell" (the one at the bottom with value `16%`), I've set fixed minimum (0%) and maximum (100%) values in an attempt to fix the size of the underlying green data bar.

**Unfortunately the data bar remains always half way full regardless of the actual value.**

I'm probably misunderstanding how this is supposed to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to set it the type to `Number` instead of `Percentage`. Then set the maximun to 1.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I guess that's because percentages are expressed as fractional [0,1] values internally?

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune Yes But you have to consider when using Percentage type, although it is also fractional values, it is the percentage of a range not a single cell as in your case.